# Trouble Compiling wxWidgets for Code::Blocks

Tags: compilation, wxwidgets, compiler-errors, codeblocks, mingw32

I am attempting to compile wxWidgets 2.8.11 on Windows 7 x64 for use with Code::Blocks, and I keep running into the same error.

I have MinGW installed as stated, and the proper things added to the path (c:\mingw\bin and c:\mingw\mingw32\bin).

I followed the instructions given here: http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Compiling_wxWidgets_2.8.6_to_develop_Code::Blocks_%28MSW%29

After cleaning, I attempt to compile, and get:

```
-DWXMAKINGDLL -Wno-ctor-dtor-privacy -MTgcc_mswudll\monodll_dummy.o -MFgcc_
ll\monodll_dummy.o.d -MD -MP ../../src/common/dummy.cpp, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
mingw32-make: *** [gcc_mswudll\monodll_dummy.o] Error 2
```

I tried getting rid of the gcc_mswudll folder, and it didn't help.

This is really frustrating.

Comment: I also noticed that many mingw files keep getting renamed (having a "~" added after the extension). So they run once, then cannot be found. This happens to mingw-get and mingw-get-0.dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I believe I solved my own problem.

I checked in the MinGW /bin, and fixed the wierd file renaming (removed the ~ from mingw32-make and mingw-get-0.dll).

For some reason, it now compiles partially, but then runs out of memory after allocating 25887232 bytes (I have 6 GB of memory, so I think it is a configuration issue).